# Connect 2 power providing USB-C devices to MacBook Air M2

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, usb, power-management

I have a "BenQ PD3420-Q9H" monitor, which is connected via USB-C to my MacBook Air M2 and delivers power to charge it. The monitor has a built-in hub, which is easy to use but not sufficient. Additionally, I also have an "OWC 11-Port Thunderbolt Dock," which also provides power when connected to the laptop. So my question is: can I connect both of them without any problems?

Comment: If you want to elaborate on any specific problems, please comment on my answer and I’ll try to address them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The system will only pull power from one source and both devices should work as USB / TB devices.